# Why would this app crash 100% when running from Testflight, maybe 10% from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, crash, sprite-kit

### EDIT: I am going to repost a different version of this - I think I was focusing too hard on the fact it crashes in Testflight and not on the fact it crashes on iPhone but not iPad. (even from TF)

I'm having an annoying problem, and previous similar answers on SO aren't helping much.

I have a game (using Sprite Kit) which sometimes crash when a certain method finishes running. It does this 10% (or less) of the time when I run it on my iPhone 5s from Xcode, but if I upload to Testflight, it does it 100% of the time.

Xcode doesn't give me great debugging info, it shows a green breakpoint line in main.m on this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

and on the left panel it says this happens in:

Thread 1:

> Queue: com.apple.spritekit.renderQueue 0
>   SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector >&,
>   SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float,
>   unsigned int&, bool)const
>
> and I see an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) in this line:
>
> 0x1015bc663:  movq   16(%rbx), %rcx

[I will attach a pic actually of the surrounding stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F73r6.png)

I am bad at debugging and I don't know what to do. One notable thing is that this never happens in the iPad version. I'm very confused as to why it would happen sometimes but not always.

Comment: It's likely a memory problem related to release mode (running from xcode is debug mode which doesn't recycle memory as heavily). Try setting the scheme Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme to 'Release' instead of debug and see if it crashes 100% of the time. Note that in release mode it's not hooked to the debugger so you won't get nice stack traces.

Comment: I switched to release mode, but the crashes are still intermittent. Weirdly though, when I go to the Log Navigator (AppleKey-8) in Xcode, it still says "Debug my-projects-name Today, 12:35pm", so maybe I'm not in release mode, but I did edit my scheme from Debug to Release in the "Run" box.

Answer (score 0):

Because of derived data app might not crash while running from xcode. Few bad access are hidden if zombies are enabled.Its all about memory reference and some thing which legally is dead but actually exists at memory location can hide a legitimate bad access.

Try deleting derived data and disable zombies you will get same bad access from xcode as well.

Comment: Also: Even Release configuration (vs Debug ) can hide a memory bug, with or without zombies.

Comment: I actually have been doing a full clean most of the time between runs, and it doesn't make a difference, the app still crashes unpredictably. I looked, and zombies were already disabled, and switching to Release mode doesn't seem to change anything.